# How to detect lane from an image using opencv and python3

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

I am new to Image Processing and am trying to detect side lanes in a given image.

This is the Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

I need an output something similar to this
So i thought of using houghTransform to detect the straight lane lines
but its providing me a large number of lines as output.
Finally i was able to filter out it to few lines as image below

This is the output obtained :

[image: output obtained]

AM sort of stuck now  and have no idea how to proceed. I  have searched online in many sites but none gave me the result i needed.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('frame3.jpg')

print(img.shape)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,100,250,apertureSize = 3)
print(img.shape[1])
print(img.shape)
minLineLength=img.shape[1]-300
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=0.02,theta=np.pi/500, 
threshold=1,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=100)

a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(img, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], 
lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)


cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
cv2.imshow('result', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you have the lines, what else do you want?

Comment: @Piglet The sample input i gave is a frame from a video. If i provide the next frame as input , my code is giving me many unwanted lines along with lane lines(some times lane lines are missing) . Is there a way to make the code work with any input that i give?

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with your code. The problem is that you want your algorithm to perform better in terms of accuracy against some desired set of outputs. StackOverflow isn't the place to ask a question like that; start by looking into how other people accomplish this task (e.g., did the first image you posted come along with an article, paper, or tutorial of how they accomplished their lane detection?), and maybe return on the [Data Science exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) to ask about how to improve your model.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to use a technology from the 1960's to accomplish a difficult task that thousands of people have worked on unsuccessfully for several decades. Only relatively recently do we have cars that warn the driver when they switch lanes without using the turn signal. And these systems don't always work. If you want to solve this problem, start by reading the recent literature on it, then look for a better solution.